# Hive : group column based on max value

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a table with fields as

```
date       value
10-02-1900 23
09-05-1901 22
10-03-1900 10
10-02-1901 24
```

....

I have to return maximum value for each year
i.e.,

```
1900 23
1901 24
```

I tried the below query but getting wrong ans.

```
SELECT YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date,'dd-mm-yyyy'))) as date,MAX(value) FROM teb GROUP BY date;
```

Can anyone suggest me a query to do this?

Comment: Why are the "dates" not in ISO format / DATE type?

Comment: P.s. `MM` is for months, `mm` for minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1

```
select      year(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date,'dd-MM-yyyy'))) as year
           ,max(value)                                             as max_value
from        t
group by    year(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date,'dd-MM-yyyy')))
;
```

#### Option 2

pre Hive 2.2.0

```
set hive.groupby.orderby.position.alias=true;
```

as of Hive 2.2.0

```
set hive.groupby.position.alias=true;
```

---

```
select      year(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date,'dd-MM-yyyy'))) as date
           ,max(value)
from        t
group by    1
;
```

---

```
+------+-----------+
| year | max_value |
+------+-----------+
| 1900 |        23 |
| 1901 |        24 |
+------+-----------+
```

P.s.

Another way to extract the year:

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date,'dd-MM-yyyy'),'yyyy')
```